# ImageIcon not finding photo, path is correct

Tags: java, swing, resources, imageicon

I'm trying to import some photos using the below code. It seems as the check I just added (if statement), comes back as "yay" so the file is there. So it can find the file works fine, but for some reason it can't import the file and create the imageIcon. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've also tried with relative path but no success!

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been pulling my hair over this for a long time now!

```
public class Photos {

    ImageIcon bi = new ImageIcon();
    // Position
    private int x, y;
    // Diameter (storlek)
    private int diameter;
    private int dynamicdiameter;

    public void importPhoto(String name) {
        String path = "/Users/Cedric/Dropbox/UU/OOPJ/Foton/src/img/";
        File imageCheck = new File(path+name);
        if(imageCheck.exists()){
            System.out.println("yay");
        }
        else{System.out.println("noo");}

            ImageIcon bi = createImageIcon(path+name, "Photo");
    }

    protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path,
                                        String description) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: How about printing the value of `imgURL` in method `createImasgeIcon()`?

Comment: What you're doing is basically the equivalent of "let's see if the file `/foo/bar/image.png` exists on my hard drive. Yay it exists. So now let's load the image from `http://google.com/foo/bar/image.png`. Oh, why doesn't it work?" A file, on your file system, is not the same thing as a resource loaded from the classpath. The syntax is different, the places where it looks for the resource are different. Read the javadoc of Class.getResource(). It does **not** expect a file path.

Comment: How are you packaging and running this? If you want to read the file from the filesystem, use `new File(path).toURI().toURL();`

Comment: If printing out imgURL it just prints a null value.
JB Nizet - I tried relative patch as well, but no success. Can you please hint what i'm missing? I tried reading the javadoc but didn't get any further. :(

Comment: It doesn't expect a relative file path either. If you want to load the image from the file system, then do as Elliott says. If you want to load it from the classpath, then pass a path starting at the root of the classpath, as explained in the javadoc. Assuming `src`is your sources directory and your IDE copies the images to the classes folder, the path would be `"/img/" + name`.

Comment: Thanks JB, I've tried "/img/" + name but without success. I'm using IntelliJ Idea as a IDE, not sure how to check if it copies the img to the classpath.

Comment: You are declaring `bi` twice. Change `ImageIcon bi = new ImageIcon();` to `ImageIcon bi ;` and more important `ImageIcon bi = createImageIcon(path+name, "Photo");` to `bi = createImageIcon(path+name, "Photo");`

Answer (score 0):

Some minor changes should make it right. See comments :

```
    public void importPhoto(String name) {

       String path = "/img/" + name;   //use correct path
        URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);

        if(imgURL != null){
            System.out.println("yay");
            bi = createImageIcon(imgURL, "Photo"); //avoid declaring a new bi
        } else {
            System.err.println("noo");
        }
    }

    protected ImageIcon createImageIcon(URL imgURL,String description) {

            return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
    }
```